# how to make shortcut in winCE using C# code?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

i need to make shortcut to any program in Windows CE using C# code

how i can do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either P/Invoke [SHCreateShortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453680.aspx) (if the OS has standard shell support) or manually create it as [a text file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms861519.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehall/archive/2005/08/22/454922.aspx) Shortcuts on Windows CE are just text files, so i guess you could use `System.IO.TextWriter` to make them.